# Is it possible to pop the UINavigationController twice?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Is it possible to pop the navigation controller twice? I have this navigation structure:

View One ----> View Two ----->   View Three

What I'd like to accomplish is that by the tap of a row on View Three, go back directly to View One. I've done it from Three to Two via protocol-delegate, but setting the delegate in view One doesn't work and setting two consecutive delegate-protocol both poping the navigation controller, gives me error: nested navigation controller activity (or something similar).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is a few pop options

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

- The first pops the top controller.
- The second allows you to pop the whole stack off to get to the root.
- The third allows you to pop to any viewController you have a reference to. You can get the viewController with `self.navigationController.viewControllers` and then work with the array to get the specific viewController you want to pop to

Answer (score 17):

Use the following code. You can use any number instead of `-3` to pop to a different level.

Obj-C:

```
ViewController *View = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count-3];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:View animated:YES];
```

Swift 3.0*:

```
let controller = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[(self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count)! - 3]        
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(controller!, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try this

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 3):

'self' seems to be released after first pop

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = self.navigationController;
[navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```